# Printing from a BlackBerry Java App

Tags: blackberry, printing

I'm writing a BlackBerry Java application and need it to submit a print request to a printer, possibly connected via Bluetooth. Buying a special printer just for the BlackBerry is an option.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks :-)

Comment: P.S. I am interested in knowing whether or not this is possible, seeing a code example, and any other relevant info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thoughts are different from writing own driver ([How to print documents](http://rim.lithium.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-print-documents/m-p/152711)) to simply sending plain text over BT ([how to take print out from blackberry,any api](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-take-print-out-from-blackberry-any-api/td-p/374353;jsessionid=6AE9EC88F484057D040015CA9B1B0382))

About using special printers and sdk:

> Brother International Corporation today introduced its new BlackBerry printing software and software development kit (SDK) for its MPrint MW-140BT mobile printer, featuring Bluetooth wireless technology.

[Brother Debuts Bluetooth Mobile Printing Software for BlackBerry Devices](http://www.beststuff.com/computers/brother-debuts-bluetooth-mobile-printing-software-for-blackberry-devices.html)

> When Planon first approached me about reviewing their PrintStik Bluetooth printer, my first thoughts were “Wow! Printing from my BlackBerry? That sounds cool.”

[PLANon PrintStik PS910 Bluetooth BlackBerry Printer review](http://www.berryreview.com/2009/01/20/review-planon-printstik-ps910-bluetooth-blackberry-printer/)

Anyway it's possible since there are applications like [Cortado Basic Print](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/362)